# Autodesk Forge App (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there an actual fix for this?

Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (c:\Source\Forge-apps\3 Legged 2.0\lib_tls_wrap.js:1530:34)
at TLSSocket.emit (c:\Source\Forge-apps\3 Legged 2.0\lib\events.js:394:28)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (c:\Source\Forge-apps\3 Legged 2.0\lib_tls_wrap.js:944:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (c:\Source\Forge-apps\3 Legged 2.0\lib_tls_wrap.js:725:12)
at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY', stack: 'Error: unable to get local issuer certificate…Trampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)', message: 'unable to get local issuer certificate'}
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:363:5)
at ServerResponse.writeHead (node:_http_server:275:11)
at ServerResponse.writeHead (c:\Source\Forge-apps\3 Legged 2.0\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:44:26)
at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (node:*http_server:266:8)
at write* (node:_http_outgoing:764:9)
at ServerResponse.end (node:_http_outgoing:853:5)
at ServerResponse.send (c:\Source\Forge-apps\3 Legged 2.0\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:221:10)
at ServerResponse.json (c:\Source\Forge-apps\3 Legged 2.0\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
at c:\Source\Forge-apps\3 Legged 2.0\start.js:25:32
at Layer.handle_error (c:\Source\Forge-apps\3 Legged 2.0\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
n

Comment: Can you please provide more information? What application exactly are you trying to run? Is it one of the apps from the learnforge.autodesk.io website? And how exactly are you running it?

Comment: Btw. the error seems to indicate that you're trying to use HTTPS without a certificate, but most of the official Forge sample apps use HTTP.

Comment: yes, you're right... Ever since IT added this machine into Azure Active Directory I've been getting this error. It used to work find before. I manage to get a certificate from them "IT" but still doesn't work.